# How do I perform branching combinatorial search without copying state at each recursive call?

Tags: algorithm, search

In most branching combinatorial search algorithms I've seen, each recursive call in the depth-first search is made with a copy of the current solution state (to ensure that the branching can always recover to the given solution state if a branch turns out to be fruitless).

For example, take Peter Norvig's Sudoku solver search function:

```
def search(values):
    "Using depth-first search and propagation, try all possible values."
    if values is False:
        return False ## Failed earlier
    if all(len(values[s]) == 1 for s in squares): 
        return values ## Solved!
    ## Chose the unfilled square s with the fewest possibilities
    n, s = min((len(values[s]), s) for s in squares if len(values[s]) > 1)
    return some(search(assign(values.copy(), s, d)) 
        for d in values[s])
```

Question: is there a standard way to avoid having to perform a copy of the entire solution/constraint space each time a recursive call is made? Concretely, Is it possible to implement Norvig's Sudoku solver without copying `values` at each recursive call?

**What have I tried?**

1) Implement search iteratively on a global solution object. Carefully manage both constructive additions and destructive removals of propagated constraints to the global solution object so that prior branch decisions are recoverable.

2) Use a persistent tree structure to represent my solution state. I haven't been able to implement this yet, and I'm not even sure it makes sense.

Comment: 1 is a good approach, basically undo the move when you need to explore neighbouring branches. You can think of it this way: you actually have all information to produce both the state before and after the move, exactly as you do, when you copy the before state to apply the move, but you only store the *difference* between the two

Comment: Right. Approach 1 is what you should do. Approach 2 does not make sense, unless the number of status is small enough to fit in reasonable memory. But in that case the combinatorial problem will be too easy to develop such a searching algorithm.